# Configure Ubuntu Linux to wake up when Samba Share is accessed?

Tags: windows, samba, wake-on-lan, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I have a Ubuntu Server 16.04 CLI System set up with a Samba share that I use for back ups, media, etc.

I'd like to put the server into hibernate mode after like 20 minutes of inactivity and then have it wake up any time the Samba Share is accessed. I know I could use the "Magic Packet" method. But as I understand it, I would have to send that magic packet anytime I wanted access to the share. (Which would require not only the additional application to send the packet, but the additional step of sending the packet as well)

Is there a more seamless solution? Can I just hibernate the server and have it wake up anytime it's accessed?

Comment: You'd have to have a transparent proxy in front that would wake the machine if needed.

Comment: Which kind of defeats the purpose of hibernating the machine. Ok.

Comment: You don't need a large machine for the proxy, a RPi or similar should work.

Comment: Good Idea. I'm re-purposing old hardware. Linux CLI is fantastic for it. Had'nt considered buying something new. I wonder if My Asus 1750 router has some type of built in functionality?